# Why does the F# compiler give an error for one case but not the other?

Tags: f#

I'm working on a platform invoke call from F#, and I am getting a compiler error I really can't make that much sense out of. First, let me show the C signature of what I am doing:

```
int Foo(
    ULONG_PTR *phHandle,
    DWORD flags
);
```

In F#, I think the correct way to invoke this natively is as so:

```
[<DllImport("somedll.dll")>]
static extern int APlatformInvokeCall
    (
        [<Out>]nativeint& phHandle,
        uint32 flags
    )
```

If I try to call this *in a class*, I get a compilation error when calling it like so:

```
type Class1() = 
    [<DllImport("somedll.dll")>]
    static extern int APlatformInvokeCall
        (
            nativeint& phHandle,
            uint32 flags
        )

    member this.Foo() =
        let mutable thing = nativeint 0
        APlatformInvokeCall(&thing, 0u) |> ignore
        thing
```

The error is:

> A type instantiation involves a byref type. This is not permitted by the rules of Common IL.

Weirdly, when I do this all in a module, the compilation errors go away:

```
module Module1 = 
    [<DllImport("somedll.dll")>]
    extern int APlatformInvokeCall
        (
            nativeint& phHandle,
            uint32 flags
        )

    let Foo() =
        let mutable thing = nativeint 0
        APlatformInvokeCall(&thing, 0u) |> ignore
        thing
```

Why does this compile as a module, but not as a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's valid to define an `extern` method within a class in F#.

If you pull up the [F# 3.0 language specification](http://fsharp.org/about/) and search for `DllImport`, near the bottom is a table listing some special attributes and how they can be used. The text for `[<DllImport>]` says:

*When applied to a function definition in a module, causes the F# compiler to ignore the implementation of the definition, and instead compile it as a CLI P/Invoke stub declaration.*

That seems to indicate that it's only valid to declare `extern` methods (that use `[<DllImport>]`) on functions defined in a module; it doesn't say anything about class members though.

I think you're running into a compiler bug. Please submit this code to `fsbugs@microsoft.com` so they can fix the error message emitted by the compiler -- it should really be giving you an error about defining an `extern` method in a class since that's not allowed by the language spec.

Comment: Hm, interesting. The odd thing about it is the pinvoke actually compiles to the correct IL even when in a class. Where it gets weirder is the compilation is successful if the external method has only one parameter. You're probably right though, I'll keep it in a module.

Answer (score 2):

Whether this is a bug not withstanding, maybe this is what's going on: If `APlatformInvokeCall` were considered a static member function, that member have a single argument of tuple type. Tuples are compiled into objects of generic type (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233200.aspx), at the bottom, or 5.1.3 in [the spec](http://fsharp.org/about/files/spec.pdf)). In this case that tuple is

```
System.Tuple<nativeint&, uint32>
```

But [ECMA 335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf) II.9.4 says you can't instantiate generic types at `byref` types. This explains the error reported.

This explanation fits the fact mentioned above that `Class1` works (well, compiles) if you modify the extern declaration and call to take instead a single argument. It also fits the fact that the module version works, since in that version there is no considering `APlatFormInvokeCall` a member function.

Comment: That does make sense. If I try to create a tuple with a nativeint& it fails with the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is to check the spec, here is the class definition grammar:

```
type type-name pat_opt as-defn)opt =
    class
        class-inherits-decl_opt
        class-function-or-value-defns_opt
        type-defn-elements
    end
```

then we have

```
class-function-or-value-defn :
      attributes_opt staticopt let rec_opt function-or-value-defns
      attributes_opt staticopt do expr
```

which doesn't allow extern.

and

```
type-defn-element :
      member-defn
      interface-impl
      interface-signature
```

which isn't what you want either.

As a result, we can see that using `extern` as you are trying to use it can't be done inside a class.

Comment: "*As a result, we can see that using `extern` as you are trying to use it.*" Huh?