# Working with SafeHandles in F#

Tags: f#, safehandle

I'm working with some F# code that uses platform invoke. One of the APIs I'm using returns a handle. Instead of using a `nativeint`, I've implemented my own SafeHandle (specifically [`SafeHandleMinusOneIsInvalid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safehandleminusoneisinvalid(v=vs.100).ASPX).) This makes working with the module containing the pinvoke signature a little clunky. Here is an example:

```
type MySafeHandle() = 
    inherit SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid(true)

    override this.ReleaseHandle() =
        NativeMethods.FreeHandle(base.handle)            
        true

module NativeMethods = 
    [<DllImport("mylibrary.dll")>]
    extern void GetHandle([<Out>]MySafeHandle& handle)
    [<DllImport("mylibrary.dll")>]
    extern void FreeHandle(nativeint handle)
```

This won't compile because the module and the class recursively reference each other, which doesn't work. If I move the module above `MySafeHandle`, then `GetHandle` won't see the SafeHandle.

I can't move the platform invoke methods inside of `MySafeHandle` since it appears that extern methods in F# [must be in modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22275072/why-does-the-f-compiler-give-an-error-for-one-case-but-not-the-other) (even though the compiler won't stop you from trying to put them in a class).

It also appears that F#'s [recursive types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233205.aspx#sectionToggle6) don't work between a module and a class, just classes.

Is there a solution to this problem that does not require declaring two different modules? Ideally I'd like to keep all of my platform invoke code organized into one module.

Comment: Two modules really is the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well I know of one, because I had the same problem myself.

The thing is, it's kinda ugly I guess:

It involves a static reference that you set to the imported function later in the module.

```
type MySafeHandle() = 
    inherit SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid(true)
    static let freeHandle = ref Unchecked.defaultof<_>
    static member internal SetFreeHandleRef value = freeHandle := value

    override this.ReleaseHandle() =
        !freeHandle base.handle            
        true

module NativeMethods = 
    [<DllImport("mylibrary.dll")>]
    extern void GetHandle([<Out>]MySafeHandle& handle)
    [<DllImport("mylibrary.dll")>]
    extern void FreeHandle(nativeint handle)

    MySafeHandle.SetFreeHandleRef FreeHandle
```